# Android: EditText content checked against button

Tags: android, android-edittext

In android studio I am trying to have a simple maths checker. The user will input an answer into an EditText and I am trying to check this answer when they click a button.

For ease, if the question is 3 + 3, the user inputs 6 into the EditText and when they click the button a toast appears to say if they are right or wrong.

I have searched for hours on the code but am new to Android Studio so not sure I have picked it up correctly.

Can anyone help?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class numbers1 extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText userAnswer;
String strInput = "";
Button answer;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers1);

    answer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String check = userAnswer.getText().toString();

            if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("6"))
            {
                strInput = strInput+","+check;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                userAnswer.setText(strInput);
                userAnswer.setText("");
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Quite. Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: what's your problem ?

Comment: when trying to run the emulator it has 12 errors of 'error: class, interface, or enum expected'. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `answer` and `userAnswer` have not been set. do this after call to `setContentView();`

Comment: put the message error so we can know where's the problem

Comment: There are 3 errors showing now. 1. error: illegal start of type. 2. error: ')' expected. 3. error: reached end of file while parsing.

Comment: having looked at the code again, its a simple issue. Apologies for wasting your time. Think i've been staring at the screen too long. The brackets towards the end were not closed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think following code is missing in your code...

```
userAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.<edittext_id>);
answer =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.<button_id>);
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, i've got that in the code now. That and not closing the setOnClickListener properly was the problem. I think i've been staring at the screen too long today. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After help from a couple of contributors and noticing I hadn't closed brackets properly, here is the correct code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class numbers1 extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText userAnswer;
String strInput = "";
Button answer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers1);

    Button answer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    final EditText userAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userAnswer);

    answer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String check = userAnswer.getText().toString();

            if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("6"))
            {
                strInput = strInput+","+check;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                userAnswer.setText(strInput);
                userAnswer.setText("");
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Quite. Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

});
}
}
```